# iOS - Performance Issues with Embedded Table View in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

A project I'm working on has a storyboard set up as follows:

Tableview controller (A) contains a tableview of static cells
Each static cell is a container view
One of these container views embeds another table view controller (B)
The table view of controller B is tableview with dynamic prototypes.

Everything works and renders appropriately, however I have begin to run into a performance problem when the number of cells in the embedded table view controller (B) becomes very large.

What seems to be happening is that iOS is allocating / attempting to render all the cells (ie calling cellForRowAtIndexPath), even those which are offscreen. This is because the embedded table is large enough to show all cells, because scrolling is disabled for this table and instead the root controller (A) scrolls the content.

Does anyone know a way to make this situation more performant when the embedded table view has a large number of cells? I thought about creating an artifically paged system where cells are only loaded when the user scrolls, however initial cells which have scrolled out of the view would still remain allocated, so I would have to set up some sort of dynamic allocation, which is what iOS already does if you simple use a single table view.

I have seen this design pattern proposed elsewhere and it seems Apple is really pushing adoption of containers as it makes for clean and modular code using storyboards, so I am hoping that there is a simple solution to this that I am missing.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you dequeuing your cells properly? You need to set a reuse identifier in your storyboard's Table View Cell, and use the matching identifier in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (as a parameter to tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:)

Comment: Yes cell is being dequeued with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. Is there any reason to ensure that cellForRowAtIndexPath is only called for visible rows? Even though the table is full height but clipped by a superview?